# Using a list of anchor to submit form and redirect

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to make a list of anchors that will submit the value of the one clicked and redirect to another page. The form is:

```
<form id="searchCategory" action="test.php" method="post">
<div id="categories">
<details>
<summary>Beers</summary>
<a href="test.php" onclick="document.getElementById("title").submit();"> <input id="title" name="title">Lager </input></a>
<a href="#"> Ale</a> //would make as above
<a href="#">Pale Lager </a> // same
</details>
</form>
```

The top of the test.php is this:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])){
include ("connection.php");

$title = (trim($_POST['title'])=="")?
die ("You did not enter any search criteria"):
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
```

The anchor redirects me to the test.php page but the value doesn't seem to be submitted.

Comment: You have quoting issues !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is invalid. Links can't contain inputs, and inputs can't contain anything.

If you want a clicked value to be submitted then there is no need for links or JavaScript. Just use submit buttons:

```
<form id="searchCategory" action="test.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Beers</legend>

        <input type="submit" name="title" value="Lager">
        <input type="submit" name="title" value="Ale">
        <input type="submit" name="title" value="Pale Lager">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I avoided doing that because I can't CSS those buttons.

Comment: Most browsers are pretty flexible about applying CSS to submit buttons.

Comment: Yes sorry ignore that comment. Realized I could just make it look like link. Thank you for your swift help.

Comment: Ah, lost in the design I hadn't noticed the submit doesn't work. =[

Comment: It does. Just make sure that if you have a submit named 'title'  you aren't checking to see if a submit named 'submit' was included in the submitted data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use here `GET` to submit your categories, just make a `GET query` after your `href`.
it is easy and make is simple

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="test.php?cat=lager">Lager</a></li>
    <li><a href="test.php?cat=ale">Ale</a></li>
    <li><a href="test.php?cat=palelager">Pale Lager</a></li>
</ul>


//handle it in test.php page or where you want 

<?php if(isset($_GET['cat'])) { 
    echo $_GET['cat'];// do anyting with cat
}
?>
```